# System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection;s current srate is open,

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection;s current srate is open,

The Software is not logging the connection is being connected to SQL Database but it is not logging in.. Please Review the Code and Help me Out Thanks in Advance

Error:

> System.InvalidOPerationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open at System.Data.ProvideBase.DBConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskComletionsource'1 retry, DbConnectionOPtions userOPtions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource'1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOPenTaskCompletionSource'1 retry) at System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlConnection.OPen() at Login.LoginForm.Login() in D:\Downloads\Compressed\SchoolManaementSystem\SchoolManagementSystem\Login'Forms\Login.cs:line 67

```
public LoginForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);

}
#region Methods
//Method For Login Form
public void LoginTeacher()
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("TeacherLogin", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Txt_User.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Txt_Pass.Text);

            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                TeacherDash teacherDash = new TeacherDash();
                this.Hide();
                teacherDash.lblusertype.Text = dataReader[1] + " " + dataReader[2].ToString();
                teacherDash.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }

}
public void Login()
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("SP_USER_LOGIN", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Txt_User.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Txt_Pass.Text);

            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                LoginTeacher();
                if (dataReader[10].Equals("Admin"))
                {

                    AdminDash adminDash = new AdminDash();
                    this.Hide();
                    adminDash.lblusertype.Text = dataReader[1] + " " + dataReader[2].ToString();
                    adminDash.ShowDialog();

                    this.Close();
                }
                else if (dataReader[10].Equals("Teacher"))
                {
                    TeacherDash teacherDash = new TeacherDash();
                    this.Hide();
                    teacherDash.lblusertype.Text = dataReader[1] + " " + dataReader[2].ToString();
                    teacherDash.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else if (dataReader[10].Equals("Accounts"))
                {
                    AccountsDash accountsDash = new AccountsDash();
                    this.Hide();
                    accountsDash.lblusertype.Text = dataReader[1] + " " + dataReader[2].ToString();
                    accountsDash.ShowDialog();

                    this.Close();
                }
                else if (dataReader[10].Equals("Addmission"))
                {
                    AdmissionDash admissionDash = new AdmissionDash();
                    this.Hide();
                    admissionDash.lblusertype.Text = dataReader[1] + " " + dataReader[2].ToString();
                    admissionDash.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (Txt_User.Text.Trim() == string.Empty & Txt_Pass.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("UserName And Password Fileds Empty", "Blank Field", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (Txt_User.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter UserName", "UserName Blank", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else if (Txt_Pass.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Password", "Password Blank", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName or Password", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
        

#endregion

private void Btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginTeacher();
    Login();
}

private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvXlE.jpg)

Comment: You are creating new connection objects in each method, but then you're really *using* the global `connection` variable. This will then be opened on the first call to something and the next call will fail when you try to open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use global `connection` variables.

> To **ensure that connections are always closed**, open the connection inside of a `using` block, as shown in the following code fragment.
>
> Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
    }
```

You can refer to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#remarks).

Comment: Does it help you? If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.